# How To Randomize Sentence Length From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is probably a simple solution to this, but for some reason I can't seem to find it on the site, or elsewhere on the net. Just trying to produce a sentence of RANDOM LENGTH from an array. Here is an example:

```
var words = ["yes", "ok", "java", "pull my hair out", "sleep"];
```

Here is the code that I'm currently using to randomize the contents of the array, but it always produces a sentence where every string is used once. I want varying sentence lengths.

```
function fisherYates(words) {
var i = words.length, j, tempi, tempj;
if ( i == 0 ) return false;
while ( --i ) {
   j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
   tempi = words[i];
   tempj = words[j];
   words[i] = tempj;
   words[j] = tempi;
   }
   return words;
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Fisher Yates is a shuffling algorithm. It doesn't change the length of the input array.

Comment: Yes I know. That's why I said I'm using it to randomize the contents of the array. I'm looking for a block of code to follow it that will produce a sentence of random length.

Comment: He uses **i** for **words.length**, so, you will catch everything. You need to set **i**, as an random number between the minimum words you want, and the maximum.

Comment: Can the output sentence include repeated words?

Comment: I'd prefer if it didn't include repeated words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want repeated strings, copy the array and *splice* random members from it to form the new collection. Just splice off a random number of strings from random positions.

```
function randWords(arr) {

  // Copy original array
  arr = arr.slice();

  // Random number of words to get
  var len = (Math.random() * arr.length + 1)|0;
  var result = [];

  // Randomly fill result from arr, don't repeat members
  while (len--) {
    result.push(arr.splice(Math.random()*arr.length|0, 1));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log( randWords(["yes", "ok", "java", "pull my hair out", "sleep"]).join(' ') );
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. For anyone wondering how to implement this, I simply declared my array before the function, then applied the function to a variable after it was defined, like so: `var words_random = randWords(arr);`. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you select a random number `m` from `1` to `n` inclusive (where `n` is the maximum length of the sentence you want). Then you randomly select `m` items from the array and put them into a new array:

```js
var words = ["yes", "ok", "java", "pull my hair out", "sleep"];

alert(randomize(words, 10).join(" ") + ".");

function randomize(array, maximum) {                 // array, n
    var length = Math.ceil(maximum * Math.random()); // m
    var result = new Array(length);
    var count  = array.length;
    var index  = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        result[index++] = array[Math.floor(count * Math.random())];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope that helps.

[image: Java Sex]

Perhaps not.

Comment: What are the odds of a repeated word?

Comment: Quite a lot, but with comical results.